# How do you effectively color balance an image using Core Image filters?

Tags: cocoa, core-image

I'm trying to add some color correction to images in my Mac app using Core Image filters. First, I'm looking at allowing a custom white-balance, to remove a cast from an image. It looked like the `CIWhitePointAdjust` was exactly what I'm looking for, but after trying it out, I'm not sure whether I'm using it wrong, or if it doesn't do what I thought.

Starting with this image, yellowed with age, and with a thin strip of white at its right edge:

[image: Original image]

I apply the filter, like so:

```
NSColor *whiteSample = // Chosen from the speech bubble's background
CIColor *whiteInputColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:whiteSample];

layer.filters = @[
    [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIWhitePointAdjust"
         withInputParameters:@{kCIInputColorKey: whiteInputColor}]
];
```

and get this image back:

[image: Image after applying CIFilter]

Note that it looks darker and yellower than the original (the opposite of my desired effect). I had been expecting an effect more like doing an **Auto Color** in Photoshop, like so:

[image: Photoshopped color balance]

Am I using `CIWhitePointAdjust` incorrectly, or is it the wrong tool for this job? If another filter or combination of filters would work better, I'd love to know.

Since I'm manipulating images that are already in `CALayer` objects, Core Image filters definitely seem like the right choice, but if this can only feasibly be done through another means, I'm open to that.

**Update**

A [helpful answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23592/15917) on the Signal Processing site give me the name of what I'm trying to implement. In broad terms, it's called Histogram Equalization. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to perform that process using Core Image filter(s) and so far, it's not looking too hopeful (without me writing my own).

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15972314/341994

Comment: @matt thanks, but I tried that already and it seemed too fiddly. The color temperature adjustment doesn't seem to do anything without also adjusting the tint, even with the tint I couldn't get the image to look right, and I don't want to have to give the user a Tint slider. It's geared toward making actual color temperature adjustments for photos, which is not my goal.

Comment: Have you tried desaturating the image a bit using CIColorControls ?

Comment: @joelg thanks, but desaturation wouldn't help. I want to allow users to correct colors, not remove color (to any degree)

Comment: Can you look at R G B individually?  Re-normalize R G B each.  You may find that the spread on one of them may be small(0 to 100), so normalize the ( 0 to 100) to (0 to 255) or some value instead of 255.

Comment: @jdl Thanks, I've read that is often the approach used for auto-color-balancing – the trick being to know where the drop-off is for each channel's histogram. Do you have an example of how to do this with Cocoa (and ideally with Core Image filters)?

Comment: @Dov, did you ever find a way to do this? All I've found so far (aside from not-working dyi examples) was https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/HistogramOperations/HistogramOperations.html.

Answer (score 6):

OK, so I think I've nailed it! Here's what I've clobbered together from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30447041/734860 and a couple of glue bits:

```
@import Accelerator;

// I haven't yet found a way to do it within Core Image

// use this when you need to CIImage* -> CGImageRef
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

...

// use this when you need to CGImageRef -> CIImage*
CIContext* context = [[CIContext alloc] init];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];

...

// the algorithm itself, which uses vImage and has to convert to/from it via CGImage
CGImageRef CreateEqualisedCGImageFromCGImage(CGImageRef original)
{
    vImage_Error err;
    vImage_Buffer _img;
    vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
        .bitsPerComponent = 8,
        .bitsPerPixel = 32,
        .colorSpace = NULL,
        .bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaFirst,
        .version = 0,
        .decode = NULL,
        .renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault,
    };

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(original);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(original);

    vImage_Buffer _dstA, _dstR, _dstG, _dstB;

    err = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&_img, &format, NULL, original, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageBuffer_Init( &_dstA, height, width, 8 * sizeof( uint8_t ), kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageBuffer_Init (alpha) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageBuffer_Init( &_dstR, height, width, 8 * sizeof( uint8_t ), kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageBuffer_Init (red) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageBuffer_Init( &_dstG, height, width, 8 * sizeof( uint8_t ), kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageBuffer_Init (green) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageBuffer_Init( &_dstB, height, width, 8 * sizeof( uint8_t ), kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageBuffer_Init (blue) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8(&_img, &_dstA, &_dstR, &_dstG, &_dstB, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8 error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&_dstR, &_dstR, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageEqualization_Planar8 (red) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&_dstG, &_dstG, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageEqualization_Planar8 (green) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&_dstB, &_dstB, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageEqualization_Planar8 (blue) error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageConvert_Planar8toARGB8888(&_dstA, &_dstR, &_dstG, &_dstB, &_img, kvImageNoFlags);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageConvert_Planar8toARGB8888 error: %ld", err);

    err = vImageContrastStretch_ARGB8888( &_img, &_img, kvImageNoError );
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageContrastStretch_ARGB8888 error: %ld", err);

    free(_dstA.data);
    free(_dstR.data);
    free(_dstG.data);
    free(_dstB.data);

    CGImageRef result = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&_img, &format, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags, &err);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
        NSLog(@"vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer error: %ld", err);

    free(_img.data);

    return result;
}
```

The merit of the solution goes all to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4735340/james-bush, but I've looked so long without success for an image-oriented solution (as opposed to the video processing discussed in that question) that I think a ready-made reply such as this one is relevant. Looking for 'AutoLevels' on OS X or iOS got me nowhere, I hope this may be useful to someone else.

Comment: please share swift version

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
import Accelerate
import Metal

extension UIImage {

func whiteBalance() -> UIImage? {
    
    // Create a vImage_Buffer from the CGImage
    
    guard let sourceRef = cgImage else { return nil }
    
    var srcBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
    
    var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bitsPerPixel: 32,
                                      colorSpace: nil,
                                      bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue),
                                      version: 0,
                                      decode: nil,
                                      renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)
    
    // init cgImage from sourceBuffer
    
    var err = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&srcBuffer, &format, nil, sourceRef, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        return nil
    }
    
    // Create dest buffers
            
    let dstWidth = sourceRef.width
    let dstHeight = sourceRef.height
            
    let pixelBits : UInt32 = UInt32(8*MemoryLayout<__uint8_t>.size)

    var dstA : vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer.init()
    var dstR : vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer.init()
    var dstG : vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer.init()
    var dstB : vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer.init()
                    
    // dstA - Alpha
                    
    err = vImageBuffer_Init(&dstA, UInt(dstHeight), UInt(dstWidth), pixelBits, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageBuffer_Init (alpha) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }
    
    // dstR - Red
    
    err = vImageBuffer_Init(&dstR, UInt(dstHeight), UInt(dstWidth), pixelBits, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageBuffer_Init (red) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }
    
    // dstG - Green
    
    err = vImageBuffer_Init(&dstG, UInt(dstHeight), UInt(dstWidth), pixelBits, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageBuffer_Init (green) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }
    
    // _dstB - Blue
    
    err = vImageBuffer_Init(&dstB, UInt(dstHeight), UInt(dstWidth), pixelBits, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageBuffer_Init (blue) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // convert to planar8
    
    err = vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8(&srcBuffer, &dstA, &dstR, &dstG, &dstB, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8 error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }
    
    // equalize red

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&dstR, &dstR, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageEqualization_Planar8 (red) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // equalize green

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&dstG, &dstG, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageEqualization_Planar8 (green) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // equalize blue

    err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&dstB, &dstB, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageEqualization_Planar8 (blue) error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // planar8 to ARGB8888

    err = vImageConvert_Planar8toARGB8888(&dstA, &dstR, &dstG, &dstB, &srcBuffer, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageConvert_Planar8toARGB8888 error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // contrast stretch

    err = vImageContrastStretch_ARGB8888( &srcBuffer, &srcBuffer, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
    
    guard err == kvImageNoError else {
        free(srcBuffer.data)
        print("vImageContrastStretch_ARGB8888 error: \(String(describing: err))")
        return nil
    }

    // free buffers

    free(dstA.data)
    free(dstR.data)
    free(dstG.data)
    free(dstB.data)
    
    // Create CGImage from vImage_Buffer
    
    guard let result = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&srcBuffer, &format, nil, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoAllocate), &err)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        
        print("vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer error: \(err))")

        return nil
    }
    
    //free(srcBuffer.data)

    // Create UIImage
    
    let destImage = UIImage(cgImage: result, scale: 0.0, orientation: imageOrientation)
    
    return destImage
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a list of possible filters with [autoAdjustmentFilters or autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIImage/autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:)... probably the latter so that you can exclude the filters that require face detection, if you plan to autoadjust cartoon scans.

Comment: That's a great idea (and I really hoped it would work), but I tried it out on the test image I'm using, and it looks like it adjusts the overall levels, but doesn't return any filters to change the color balance. Specifically, it returns these filters: `CIVibrance`, `CIToneCurve`, and `CIHighlightShadowAdjust`). That's disappointing :-(